# guide_legend() to make legend icons smaller not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1)))`  to modify the legend icon size (make them smaller) in ggplot2().

It doesn't work; I've tried changing `colour` to `fill` since that's what I'm calling in `aes` but that doesn't do the trick either.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
# Libraries  
library(ggplot2)

# Dataframe 
df <- data.frame(location=c("all","all","south","south","north","north"),gender=c("female","male","female","male","female","male"),proportion=c(72.5,27.5,71.3,28.7,75.2,24.8))

# Plot 
p_mwe <- ggplot(df, aes(x=location,y=proportion,fill=gender)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + theme_classic() + coord_flip()+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gray88","gray44")) + xlab("")+ ylab("prop (%)") +labs(fill="") +
  theme(legend.position="top",legend.text = element_text(colour="black", size=10)) +  ggtitle("a) MWE plot") + guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1)))
```

Comment: First off, you definitely want `fill` as in `guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=1)))`. Second, this does affect the size of the legend square icon, but not predictably. There seems to some kind of minimum size being imposed. Try in combination with `theme(legend.text=element_text(size=5))` to see what I mean.